# Using php; I would like to check mysql db to ensure there is no records of the same email address prior to sign up

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here's my form:

```
<section class="loginform tmr">
    <form name="login" action="welcome.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label for="username">Username: </label><br />
            <?php if (isset($input_errors['username'])) { echo '<div class="error">' . $input_errors['username'] . '</div>'; } ?>
            <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Handle" required><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="sign_up_date" value="<?php echo $_POST['sign_up_date'] ?>">
        <label for="usermail">Email: </label><br />
            <?php if (isset($input_errors['usermail'])) { echo '<div class="error">' . $input_errors['usermail'] . '</div>'; } ?>
            <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required><br />
        <label for="password">Password: </label><br />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    </section>
```

Here's all my validation on my insert:

```
$input_errors = array();

if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
} else {
    $input_errors['username'] = "Must fill out username";
}

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usermail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (false === $email) {
    $input_errors['usermail'] = "Not a valid email address";
}

if(count($input_errors) > 0) {
    print_r($input_errors); die();
}

else {
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Init failed";
} else {
    $cmd = "INSERT INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW() )";
    if ($stmt->prepare($cmd)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $email );
        $stmt->execute();

        echo $stmt->affected_rows . " row(s) inserted";

        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        echo "Prepare failed";
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }
}
```

I want to check username and email and if either are in use than alert the new registration user...

I'm thinking that my server side validation stuff is getting so messy that maybe i should build a class for this...??

That's not necessarily something i need help with atm.. I really just want to check mysql using best practices if the email is in use or the username is in use..

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to check check the query to see if there is more than 1 row...

Answer (score 0):

try below or follow link [php mysqli check if any result exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639598/php-mysqli-check-if-any-result-exist)

```
<?php
    function user_exists($email) {
        $query = "SELECT 1 FROM " . USER_TABLE . " WHERE email = ?";
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array($email));
        return (bool)$stmt->fetchColumn();
    }

    //do your stuff here same for username
    if(user_exits($register_email))
```

Comment: An answer, that actually consists of just a link to another answer, should be a comment

Comment: So do you just pick questions at random or are you always not minding your own business? I'm surprised this one didn't get the same treatment. @YourCommonSense

Comment: @Your Common Sense if i have only comment answer i always include another QA links but when i give an answer it's will helpful for understand answer so i included this is this any problem?

Comment: I wouldn't say that a code that uses totally different API is "helpful for understand"

Comment: @Your Common Sense ok i will use this sense in future :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not sure I get your question and what business you are talking about, but surely one can open any random question under PHP tag and find out that most answers are of unacceptable quality, written out of a wild guess, or a mindless copy-paste, or a mere confusion.

Comment: Next time you downvote an answer, don't be a coward by not leaving a comment as to "why" you downvote an answer, but instead give a comment in order to "participate" in "improving" it, not by condoning it. @YourCommonSense And don't tell me you don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if you're talking of your answer, I was going to commentbut you deleted it. Speaking of downvotes in general - I disagree with you. I believe that one who bothers to answer, should *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.*

Comment: I actually understood the problem being solved and I will agree, however the problem to start off with, is that the OP (in my view) was going about it the wrong way and using the wrong approach/code; hence my suggestive answer. Why it got downvoted, I'll never know, but that's what I use at times and it works. @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 0):

This code selects the number of rows with either username or email:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM people WHERE username = ? 
       OR email = ?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

    if ($data['amount'] > 0)
    {
        print "User already exists";
    }
}
```

Comment: i copy and pasted that into my code and got this error... Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: @cookinggood Maybe, you don't have $conn variable defined. Use `$mysqli` instead.

Comment: These questions are so nice to farm, aren't they?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah, more such questions, and we'll get a lot of rep.

Comment: What does farm mean? lol.. just get more rep?

Comment: I have $conn defined. Someone posted a link as possible duplicate and i checked that thread and there was no answer.

Comment: @cookinggood Don't mind. We must solve the problem. I saw, that you use "$mysqli->" in your code. I updated the answer. Please, try it.

Comment: I saw your update.. you added $mysqli->prepare... now i'm getting this error  ...  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Comment: @cookinggood When you run my request in phpmyadmin with appropriate values instead of '?', does it work?

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: That's the usual problem with copy-pasted code

Comment: @cookinggood What's the variable name for your connection?

Comment: Why so positive? @YourCommonSense